# Do Filipino citizens need a transit visa when traveling through Paris and Hong Kong to Manila?

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, filipino-citizens

Our crew disembarking from Panama are booked on the following flights:

PTY-CDG — Panama-Paris
CDG-HKG — Paris-Hong Kong
HKH-MNL — Hongkong-Manila

Does our crew need to have a visa/documentation from Panama since they will be having flight on Paris?

Comment: Does the crew member have a Seaman's Book?

Comment: Any special transit rules for crewmembers apply at your point of embarkation or disembarkation from your vessel. The other transits are just regular transits and the normal airside transit rules for those locations will apply.

Comment: You can use http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area to find out. The answer seems to be that a transit visa is generally required for Filipino citizens in Paris. They might qualify for an exemption based on another visa (e.g. US visa, even if it's not used for this particular trip) or their status as seamen (not sure about that one) but otherwise they would need to obtain an "airport transit visa" in advance.

Comment: @Relaxed that should be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Filipino citzens need to get an *airport transit* visa in advance to transit in Paris. There are exemptions for people with valid visas from a few other countries (like the US or Canada) and for seamen (but possibly only when joining a ship in a French harbour) that might apply in some cases but generally speaking a visa is required.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Timatic, the database used by airlines:

For [France](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=fr&SUBSECTION=CR&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

> Visa **not** required if traveling on duty and holding a Crew
>     License or a Crew Member Certificate according to the
>     Chicago Convention of 7 December 1944. Crew must wear uniform and duration of stay is according to
>     the General Declaration.

For [Hong Kong](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=hk&SUBSECTION=CR&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

> Visa **not** required for those arriving as Operational Crew for
>     a stay of max. 7 days (extension possible).

So no, your crew does **not** need visas.

Comment: The question does not positively indicate that the crew in question is an airplane crew. “Disembarking from Panama” suggests a ship to me (and, at the risk of furthering a stereotype, Filipino citizenship is not incongruent with that).